# Devise (Email Cant Be Blank Error Only On Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

edit: added routes.rb file
rails 3.2 ruby 1.92

I have a standard devise implementation to have users enter their email addresses only.

When i run the app in dev it works fine, also when i run the app locally in prod (rails s -e production) it works fine.

However once i push it to heroku and try to submit an email address i get error "email cant be blank"

- I have tried using the devise strong parameter settings with no luck,
- i made sure all my application.yml config settings are also set on heroku.
- besides the method overrides in my user model i made no further changes to devise config.

my logs locally when i submit an email

```
 Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-13 15:44:33 -0500
 Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3DQbumWdQ+HXTlrHo3cbCXWo2YVKDRXZLArypVyH05s="}
 Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
 Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.0ms)
 Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 25.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

my log entry from heroku when i submit an email

```
  Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"nancy@drew.com"}}
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb (31.8ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 173ms (Views: 44.9ms | ActiveRecord: 21
```

routes.rb

```
  Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  devise_scope :user do
  root :to => "devise/registrations#new"
  match '/user/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :put, :as =>  :update_user_confirmation
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations",      :confirmations => "confirmations" }
  match 'users/bulk_invite/:quantity' => 'users#bulk_invite', :via => :get, :as => :bulk_invite
  resources :users do
   get 'invite', :on => :member
  end
 end
```

Registrations Controller

```
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # override #create to respond to AJAX with a partial
   def create
   build_resource

if resource.save
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    (render(:partial => 'thankyou', :layout => false) && return)  if request.xhr?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    (render(:partial => 'thankyou', :layout => false) && return)  if request.xhr?
    respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  render :action => :new, :layout => !request.xhr?
end
end

 protected

 def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
# the page prelaunch visitors will see after they request an invitation
# unless Ajax is used to return a partial
'/thankyou.html'
 end

 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
# the page new users will see after sign up (after launch, when no invitation is    needed)
redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

my user model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

 # override Devise method
 # no password is required when the account is created; validate password when the user sets one
 validates_confirmation_of :password
 def password_required?
if !persisted?
  !(password != "")
else
  !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
 end
 end

# override Devise method
def confirmation_required?
false
end

# override Devise method
def active_for_authentication?
confirmed? || confirmation_period_valid?
 end

def send_reset_password_instructions
if self.confirmed?
  super
else
  errors.add :base, "You must receive an invitation before you set your password."
end
end

 # new function to set the password
 def attempt_set_password(params)
p = {}
p[:password] = params[:password]
p[:password_confirmation] = params[:password_confirmation]
update_attributes(p)
end

 # new function to determine whether a password has been set
 def has_no_password?
self.encrypted_password.blank?
 end

# new function to provide access to protected method pending_any_confirmation
 def only_if_unconfirmed
pending_any_confirmation {yield}
 end
```

Comment: Are you sure all your files are added to your git repository? From your logs it looks like in heroku it is not sending your form to the same controller.

Comment: i am sure thats not the issue i actually went back and removed all entreis from my git ignore and got same issue. could be an issue with the routes.rb file?

Comment: I think it's an issue with your registrations controller. I think your changes have caused some issues to arise. I could write an answer if you wanted? I doubt I'd get the answer in the first run though

Comment: @roberto poo I guess my main confusion is why it would work locally in production but not when pushed to Heroku. I would think if the issue was with the controller it would have showed up locally as well. Do you have any recommendations on what to change in the controller? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Try doing `git status` in the project folder, and show us the output. I think the most probable problem is that you are pushing all code to heroku, that is why it is different than locally.